# Prediction using a natural spline fit

Tags: r, spline

I have a fitted a simple natural spline (df = 3) model and I'm trying to predict for some out of sample observations. Using the function `predict()`, I'm able to get fitted values for in-sample observations but I've not been able to get the predicted value for new observations.

Here is my code:

```
library(splines)

set.seed(12345)
x <- seq(0, 2, by = 0.01)
y <- rnorm(length(x)) + 2*sin(2*pi*(x-1/4))

# My n.s fit:
fit.temp <- lm(y ~ ns(x, knots = seq(0.01, 2, by = 0.1)))

# Getting fitted values:
fit.temp.values <- predict(fit.temp,interval="prediction", level = 1 - 0.05)

# Plotting the data, the fit, and the 95% CI:
plot(x, y, ylim = c(-6, +6))
lines(x, fit.temp.values[,1], col = "darkred")
lines(x, fit.temp.values[,2], col = "darkblue", lty = 2)
lines(x, fit.temp.values[,3], col = "darkblue", lty = 2)

# Consider the points for which we want to get the predicted values:
x.new <- c(0.275, 0.375, 0.475, 0.575, 1.345)
```

***How can I get the predicted values for x.new?***

Thanks very much for your help,

p.s. I searched all related questions on SO and I didn't find the answer.

Comment: There are some easy solutions specially for the example above. ***My point is to learn to use `predict()` function to get predicted values for out-of-sample observations.***

Comment: Your first step should have been reading `?predict.lm`.

Comment: Hi @Roland, thanks for your comment. I did. The problem is I don't know how "newdata" should be when we have ns() among our covariates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a data frame with a column called `x`, and pass it as the `newdata` argument to `predict`:

```
predict(fit.temp, newdata=data.frame(x=x.new))
```

Comment: Thanks @Hong Ooi. I tried that before posting my question but I didn't put x in the data.frame and I got error. Now the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending individual vectors to `lm`. If you want to see what is going wrong here, then type:

```
 fit.temp$terms
```

... and notice that the name of the x-predictor is:

```
attr(,"term.labels")
[1] "ns(x, knots = seq(0.01, 2, by = 0.1))"
```

You would need to give `predict` a list with that as a name for `x`. Much easier would be to use `lm` and `lm.predict` with a dataframe argument so that the predictions could be done with internal re-evaluation of the new values.

```
 df <- data.frame(x,y)
 # My n.s fit:
 fit.temp <- lm(y ~ ns(x, knots = seq(0.01, 2, by = 0.1)) , data=df)
 predict(fit.temp, newdata=list(x =c(0.275, 0.375, 0.475, 0.575, 1.345) )  )
#        1         2         3         4         5 
#0.9264572 1.6549046 2.0743470 1.9507962 0.8220687 
points(x.new, predict(fit.temp, 
               newdata=list(x =c(0.275, 0.375, 0.475, 0.575, 1.345) )), 
       col="red", cex=2)
```

Comment: Actually, `predict.lm` is smart enough to work out that the underlying variable is `x`. No need to collect the variables in a data frame (although that's still generally a good idea).

Comment: So the OP was only failing because he wasn't using `list(x=new.x)`? I'm so embarrassed.

Comment: Thank you both for helping me. The problem is I used x.new itself rather than putting it in a data.frame and I got errors. Now the issue is fixed.

Comment: It's more that you didn't name it "x" in the argument you gave to predict. Coercion to class 'data.frame' is attempted by the function.

Comment: OK. Done. I also tried to add either `lowess` or `lowess`, but neither of them exist yet as tags.

Comment: No. I tried and failed. Apparently neither tag exists yet. I do understand they are different. The parametric splines you cited allow specification of hte basis, while lowess and loess are locally smoothed splines with less control available.